# How to make a backup of live USB Ubuntu?

Tags: backup, 17.04, format

I made a live Ubuntu 17(not technically 17 but a beta version) usb.

I have two questions:

1. How do i make a backup of this live usb. Some kind of an image,
   incase    some bad stuffs happen to the drive. So i could restore
   the usb    Ubuntu ver.

   I tried using Clonezilla but it quite didn't work as it couldn't recognize the drive, it says broken image all the time, believe me! i tried every option. Didn't work.

   I believe the file system that it made Ubuntu installable in a USB is the cause. Because i think Clonezilla is still a Win backup program. Yaaa.
2. In case i need this drive (using 8GB USB) to be formatted, how do i
   achieve this.

   Because when i insert the USB when i m on 32bit Win 7 PC, it doesn't recognize the drive and instead it says, format the drive in order to use it.

Doing so could possibly brick my USB and could cause some sector problems. It could possibly be rendered useless. I have had that experience before.

I bricked my 16 GB usb once, when it was still new. Don't want to repeat it again.

I do have gparted and mparted live CD, handy.

So i just need to know, what would you do, incase you need that usb (which has been formatted by Ext Journalising 4 file format system); to format in fat32 file system and use it in Win PC.

So:

1. Make a backup of live USB.
2. How to format a live Ubuntu USB in a Win PC(without bricking it).

Comment: What's the purpose of backing up a "liveUSB" when you can a new one the same way? Everything else is a moot point.

Comment: **Are you talking about a cloned live-only USB drive, that is read-only?** In that case @MichaelBay's question is relevant, because all information is in the iso file, so it is the ultimate backup. **But there are other scenarios.** Maybe it is an **extracted system**, where you can store files alongside the live-only system. Maybe it is a **persistent live system**, where you can store files and install application programs. In these cases backup is a good idea. If you create a persistent live system with **mkusb**, you will get shellscripts for backup and restore (of the casper-rw partition.

Comment: You can format a USB pendrive in a reliable way with mkusb 'Restore to a standard storage device'. See this link, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb and this link, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/wipe

Comment: I read '**formatted by Ext Journalising 4 file format system**', which makes me think that it is an installed system in a USB pendrive. Do you want to restore to the same kind of partition with an `ext4` file system? In this case **gparted** can do the job, and it can be done **from a(nother) live USB drive**, a live CD/DVD, or a live memory card. You can also install gparted in an installed Ubuntu system and do it from there, but Windows will not help you create `ext4`.

Comment: I looked at your previous question, https://askubuntu.com/questions/956945/how-to-make-live-usb-ubuntu-17, and now I am rather sure, that you have an installed system in the USB drive. **I think Clonezilla is a good tool for backup of your system**. I have used it to backup systems from USB drives. You can clone a drive of at least the same size, or you can make a compressed image (a directory with several files, the big ones are compressed). You can restore from the image to a drive of at least the same size. I think I can help you make it work. Otherwise there are other tools e.g. mkusb.

Comment: Thank you guys for showing interest in this thread.
@sudodus Well i am on a installed system i.e., on the USB drive.
Previously i had asked for help on how to install or make a live bootable Ubuntu USB. Which i did, now its just backup and format the drive.
Makeusb shows lot of promising feature that i could use to backup and probably format the usb. However there is no download links in your comments. So i need to download and test this tool for quite some days.
I'll keep updating. Till then lets test this software.

Comment: See this link, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb and this link, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=mkUSB-quick-start-manual-12.pdf . Install mkusb via the PPA.

Comment: ... and you find Clonezilla via this link, http://clonezilla.org -- descriptions as well as links to tutorials and iso files to download.

Comment: Thank you, the latest version of Clonezilla (i.e.,clonezilla-live-20170905-zesty-i386.iso) did it for me.It recognized the Ext Journalizing file system 2/3/4.
Just made an Image and the backup came close to 2.5 GB from a 8 GB Live USB.
I prefere using the Interface version as it is easier to visualize then the commandline version. Thank you sudo, for redirecting, just in time after making an update of Audio and Video plugins and vlc.
My Live USB Ubuntu is up and ready, prepared.

Thank you.